# Why is my JSON Array in php not printing correctly in my Android App?

Tags: php, arrays, json

In my PHP file I have code including:

```
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

  //make an array called $results
    $results = array();

    $results[] = array(
    'contact_phonenumber' => $row['username'], 
         );


    $json2 = json_encode($results); 
   //this is the response which we want in the Android app
    echo $json2;
```

And in my Android App I have:

```
public void onResponse(String response) {
   //print the JSON Array from the php file
   System.out.println("the jsonarray is : " + response;
```

The `response` I get when I print is in the format :

```
[{"contact_phonenumber":"+11111"}][{"contact_phonenumber":"+22222"}][{"contact_phonenumber":"+33333"}][{"contact_phonenumber":"+44444"}][{"contact_phonenumber":"+55555"}]
```

But shouldn't it be in the format ? :

```
[{"contact_phonenumber":"+11111"}, {"contact_phonenumber":"+22222"},{"contact_phonenumber":"+33333"}, {"contact_phonenumber":"+44444"},{"contact_phonenumber":"+55555"}]
```

How can I acheive this?

Comment: You're not creating a proper json. You're creating multiple json strings.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$result = [];
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  array_push(['contact_phonenumber' => $row['username']], $result);
}
$json2 = json_encode($result); 
//this is the response which we want in the Android app
echo $json2;
```

Comment: @MagnusEriksson haha seemed like the most simple way, it just makes what's going on a bit clearer. Updated answer to include your comments.

Comment: In my question $results and $result are two different things. In my Android logcat I get nothing in the array, just the message ' Only variables can be passed by reference in filename.php on line 66, which is 'array_push(['contact_phonenumber' => $row['username']], $result);' You know what the problem is here?